# Flows in Order of Execution

Tags: trigger, flow

I have a flow which creates the Order record and also there is an after insert trigger on Order.I am trying to understand which one executes first

I have assignment of Order shipping address on Fast Create element from flow and in trigger there is an update of shipping address.But it looks like some action which is not shown in the debug log the address is getting deleted.

here is the history on the order record

[image]

Comment: Where in the flow is the Order shipping address being updated? If you're setting the address on an sObject variable or specifying the field values on a Record Create or Fast Create element, then those values would be inserted, and then the `after insert` trigger would fire and overwrite them. If you're doing the Record Create/Fast Create first, and in a subsequent Flow step you're updating the shipping address fields and updating the record, then the `after insert` trigger would fire on the initial insert, but not again on the update.

Comment: I have shipping address assignment before the FastCreate element

Comment: In your picture, which of those actions is being taken by the trigger?

Comment: trigger is updating the address to 1250 20th St NW,Washington

Comment: Is the trigger also changing the Status? Are there any other triggers or workflows on Order? Are the Shipping Street and Shipping City being explicitly set to null in the Flow before the Fast Create?

Comment: trigger is not changing the status..Its the flow that is doing it..Shipping street and City is set by Account Shipping Street and Account City which is not null

Comment: I figured it out there is actually an update of status in flow which is setting the address to null.Thank you Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're setting the address fields on an sObject variable and then using a Fast Create element, those values would be inserted initially, and then the `after insert` trigger would fire and overwrite them.